# Keep column if any row contain specific value in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I have a dataframe such as :

```
    COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 
A   X    A    B    X    NA
B   NA   A    A    X    NA
C   NA   NA   A    NA   X
D   X    NA   NA   A    NA
```

and I would like to remove all column where there is no (A or B value)

and Get

```
    COL2 COL3 COL4
A   A    B    X
B   A    A    X
C   NA   A    NA
D   NA   NA   A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
df[sapply(df, function(x) any(c('A','B') %in% x))]
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  COL2  COL3  COL4 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     B     X    
2 A     A     X    
3 NA    A     NA   
4 NA    NA    A
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  COL1  COL2  COL3  COL4  COL5 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 X     A     B     X     NA   
2 NA    A     A     X     NA   
3 NA    NA    A     NA    X    
4 X     NA    NA    A     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

`tidyverse` alternative, for the fun :

```
df %>%
  select(where(~ any(.x %in% c("A", "B"))))
```